# Reduction formulae question.

Tags: integration

$I_n=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}(1-2x)^ne^xdx$

Prove that for $n\ge1$
$$I_n=2nI_{n-1}-1$$

I end up (by integrating by parts) with: $I_n =e^x(1-2x)^n+2nI_{n-1}$

I am not sure how $e^x(1-2x)^n$ becomes $-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle I_n=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}(1-2x)^ne^xdx$

$=\displaystyle [(1-2x)^n\int e^{x}dx]_{0}^{1/2}-\int_{0}^{1/2}((\int e^xdx) (\frac{d}{dx}(1-2x)^{n}))dx$

$\displaystyle =[(1-2x)^ne^{x}]_{0}^{1/2}-\int_{0}^{1/2}e^xn(-2)(1-2x)^{n-1}dx$

$\displaystyle =[(1-2x)^ne^{x}]_{0}^{1/2}+2n\int_{0}^{1/2}e^x(1-2x)^{n-1}dx$

$\displaystyle =-1+2nI_n$

$[(1-2x)^ne^{x}]_{0}^{1/2}=(1-2.\frac{1}{2})^ne^{1/2}-(1-2.0)e^0=-1$

Comment: my question is why does $(1-2x)^ne^{x}]_{0}^{1/2} =-1$

Comment: When you apply $x=1/2$ you get $(1-2\frac{1}{2})^n\exp(\frac{1}{2})=0$, while applying $x=0$ you get $(1-0)^n\exp(0)=1$, as $1^n=1$ and $\exp(0)=1$. The difference between the two contributions is then equal to $-1$.

Comment: Now I think its clear @maxmitch ???

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$\int(1-2x)^ne^xdx$$

$$=(1-2x)^n\int e^xdx-\int\left(\frac{(1-2x)^n}{dx}\int e^xdx\right)dx$$

$$=(1-2x)^ne^x-\int\left(n(1-2x)^{n-1}(-2)e^x\right)dx$$

$$=(1-2x)^ne^x+2n\int (1-2x)^{n-1}e^x dx$$

$$\implies \int_0^{\frac12}(1-2x)^ne^xdx=\left[(1-2x)^ne^x\right]_0^{\frac12}+\int_0^{\frac12} (1-2x)^{n-1}e^x dx$$

$$\text{Now,   }(1-2x)^ne^x\big|_0^{\frac12}=0-1=-1$$

Comment: I dont think you can apply integration by parts in case of indefinite integrals.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu, Is integration by parts applicable only for definite integral? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: I am not sure..... yet i am saying that look at the derivation they have used the fact that they are integrating it over an interval.....

Comment: Moreover the proof I know also integrates it over an interval and then uses the fundamental theorem of calculus. It would appretiate if you can prove it for the indefinite case using the definite case.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu, please substantiate "I dont think you can apply integration by parts in case of indefinite integrals"